# Save all open .m files in the editor at once

Tags: matlab, keyboard, save

Running the code, getting the old results... Indeed, forgot to save one of the edited .m files, again. What's the keyboard shortcut to save ALL open .m files at once?

Comment: AAAhhhh those damn asterisks! I also want to know

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a shortcut for the **Save All** action (at least in R2015a which I am using).

I chose `CTRL+ALT+S`:
[image]

How you get there is described in the [MATLAB documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/keyboard-shortcuts.html):

> On the Home tab, in the Environment section, click Preferences. Select MATLAB > Keyboard > Shortcuts.

Comment: Thx. I chose the same :).

Comment: Don't know how to do this.

Comment: @user2983876 have a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work